# Efficient algorithm to create polygons from a 2D mesh? (vertices+edges)

Tags: algorithm, polygon, mesh, vertices, edges

Given a mesh consisting of a list of vertices (2D coordinates) and edges (as vertex pairs), like so:

[image: Mesh]

So the edges are defined like this:

```
a: 2,3 
b: 3,4
c: 4,8
d: 5,8
e: 6,7
etc..
```

Edges are orientation-neutral, i.e. the order of any two vertices that define an edge is random (edges are not clockwise or counter clockwise).

Polygons may be convex or concave, but they never overlap or self-intersect (edges never cross eachother).

**Question: how do I generate a list of all polygons?**

More specifically, in the above example I would need 4 polygons, like so:

```
(a,b,c,d,i)
(d,g,h)
(f,i,j,k)
(e,h,k)
```

The polygons have no orientation either, clockwise or counterclockwise does not apply, and in fact the order of the edges that define a polygon may be random as well. For example (a,i,d,b,c) for the 5-sided one would be fine as well.

Instead of defining polygons as a list of edges, it could also be a list of connected vertices, like so:

```
(2,3,4,8,5)
(6,5,8)
(2,5,7,1)
(7,6,5)
```

In this case, the order of the vertices cannot be random (the list of vertices should be a circular sequence) but orientation (clockwise or counterclockwise) is still irrelevant. So the 4-sided polygon could also be (5,2,1,7) or (1,7,5,2) et cetera.

What is an **efficient** (fast) way to construct a list of polygons, defined in either edges or vertices?

Comment: I see many more polygons than the listed four. `(j,i,h,e,f)` `(a,b,c,g,h,i)` etc. How do you reject those ?

Comment: Are these supposed to be vertices at certain X/Y locations?

Comment: Can a polygon contain a hole? E.g. (7,1,3,6,7) and (7,2,5,7) - is that considered one polygon with a hole, or two overlapping polygons?

Comment: Here is an idea, start a depth first search from a given node and when you hit that node in the path again, you have found a polygon ! Add the path to a global list of polygons. When you are done searching from a node (ex. node 1), mark it, you have found all possible polygons involving that node and subsequent searches originating at any node should not visit an already marked node. Repeat this process for all nodes in your graph and you should have all possible polygons.

Comment: @RandomGuy Those polygons would be separated by internal edges. As long as a polygon can be divided up into smaller polygons, I want to include only the smaller ones in my resulting list.

Comment: @Amit Yes, they're just points in a 2D plane.

Comment: @RocketNuts - I meant are there specific x/y coordinates for each point, or does the definition only include the connections. If the latter, the problem is undefined.

Comment: @Amit Right, I see what you mean. Yes the x,y coordinates for all vertices are explicitly defined. As are the connections.

Answer (score 2):

For each edge `vw`, generate two half-edges `v->w` and `w->v`. Partition these by head (the head of `x->y` is `y`). Within each partition, sort by angle (if you use a comparison sort, then there's a way to avoid trig).

For your sample graph, the result is

```
7->1, 2->1
1->2, 5->2, 3->2
2->3, 4->3
8->4, 3->4
7->5, 6->5, 8->5, 2->5
8->6, 5->6, 7->6
6->7, 5->7, 1->7
5->8, 6->8, 4->8
```

. Now, define a permutation where `v->w` maps to the half-edge following `w->v` in the list containing `w->v` (wrapping around if necessary). The cycles of this permutation are the polygons.

For example, `5->8` maps to `2->5` (after `8->5`) maps to `3->2` (after `5->2`) maps to `4->3` (after `2->3`) maps to `8->4` (after `3->4`) maps to `5->8` (after `4->8`).

Comment: Awesome, I need to contemplate a bit about why this works, but it looks smart and efficient. Thanks!

Comment: With trig-free comparison, do you mean taking the sign of the Z coord of the cross product?

Comment: I think there's still a problem: this would also find the exterior of the entire mesh as a polygon. The outer half-edges together will form a polygon which don't want to include. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @RocketNuts Yeah, you can filter that one by finding one its half-edges (vertex with the greatest y coordinate, first adjacency by atan2 angle order I think; something like this should work).